# Excel Pivot Charts - Creating different charts (with different grouping) from the same data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, office365, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I would like to create (at least) two pivot charts sourced from the same data that display the data in different groupings; one will be grouped by years, the other grouped by months. I am able to create the two charts each on their own, but as soon as I create them both on the same Sheet/Workbook, they become linked and changing one changes the other.

The data for these charts is updated weekly so I don't want to create entirely separate workbooks for each set of data I'm hoping to display in more than one way.

Is there anyway to 'unlink' the charts from themselves while still keeping them sourced from the same data? Something to do with data models? (I know the word but have never used anything in there.)

---

Example data:

| PO_Number | PO_Date_Created |
| --- | --- |
| 144867 | 6/2/2022 |
| 134028 | 4/18/2022 |
| 145140 | 6/8/2022 |
| 141421 | 5/23/2022 |
| 145623 | 6/17/2022 |
| 94305 | 9/9/2021 |
| 142399 | 5/24/2022 |
| 145629 | 6/17/2022 |
| 132022 | 4/8/2022 |
| 144968 | 6/6/2022 |
| 145587 | 6/17/2022 |
| 145617 | 6/17/2022 |
| 145631 | 6/17/2022 |
| 145299 | 6/13/2022 |
| 135080 | 4/29/2022 |

---

Here is the set up. I'd like one for Months and one for Years; however, since I set the Month one up after configuring Years, it overrode the first chart.

[image: ExampleOfLinked]

Each graph works, just not at the same time.

[image]

Any tips or things to try would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you **[unshare a data cache between Pivot tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unshare-a-data-cache-between-pivottable-reports-87188806-0c24-4d17-b2f7-9e3a4a05542b?)**. However, please note this action will increase the size of the workbook.

It is preferred to ensure that 2 or more pivot tables are independent.

Select one cell in the upper left corner of one PivotTable, press Alt and D, then press P to open the "PivotTable and PivotChart Wizard".

[image]

Click "Back", select the new data source area, select Next.

[image]

Then verify that the PivotTable is displayed at the previously selected cell location (the upper left corner of the PivotTable), then click Finish,

The same steps are used to change the data source for other pivot tables.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to follow the instructions from the MS website you linked, but simply going through what is in your answer doesn't quite get us there. 

Basically once the charts are created, you need to change the source of one to something else, which forces a new cache to be created, and then change it back to include all the data it did originally. It retains the separate cache.